# How to weight classes using fit_generator() in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use keras to fit a CNN model to classify images. The data set has much more images form certain classes, so its unbalanced.

I read different thing on how to weight the loss to account for this in Keras, e.g.: 
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras, which is nicely explained. But, its always explaining for the **fit**() function, not the **fit_generator**() one.

Indeed, in the fit_generator() function we dont have the '**class_weights**' parameter, but instead we have '**weighted_metrics**', which I dont understand its description: "weighted_metrics: List of metrics to be evaluated and weighted by sample_weight or class_weight during training and testing."

How can I pass from 'class_weights' to 'weighted_metrics'? Would any one have a simple example?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on [cs.SE] and not on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We have `class_weight` in `fit_generator` (**Keras v.2.2.2**) According to [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator):

> **Class_weight**: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to
>   a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during
>   training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more
>   attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

Assume you have two classes [*positive* and *negative*], you can pass `class_weight` to `fit_generator` with:

```
model.fit_generator(gen,class_weight=[0.7,1.3])
```

Comment: I think class_weight must be having a dictionary type. Passing a list or np array is throwing error.