# How to solve problem of imbalanced data using fit_generator

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, imbalanced-data

I want to use `class_weights` in my keras model to balance my dataset but I don't know how to use it incase of `fit_generator. I want to solve problem of imbalanced data

Any help would be appreciated

```
generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
            x=np.array([x])
            x=x.swapaxes(0,1)
            if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)     
            yield(x,y)
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
            np.unique(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=100)), generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=100))
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=100),
               validation_data=generate_arrays_for_validation(indexPat, filesPath_validation, end=100), 
               steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100))), 
               validation_steps=int((len(filesPath_validation) int(len(filesPath_validation)/100))),#*75),
               verbose=2,class_weight=class_weights,
               epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback,checkpoint])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to weight classes using fit\_generator() in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118525/how-to-weight-classes-using-fit-generator-in-keras)

Comment: @N.Kiefer I don't the weight that suits my data.