# How to balance dataset using fit_generator() in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generator

I am trying to use keras to fit a CNN model to classify 2 classes of data . I have imbalanced dataset I want to balance the data. I don't know can I use class_weight in `model.fit_generator` . I wonder if I used `class_weight="balanced"`  in  `model.fit_generator`

**The main code**:

```
def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):      
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f) 
            x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0) 
            
            if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            yield(x,y)   
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), 
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, start=75),
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*25))), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(filesPath)-int(len(filesPath)/100*75))),
                                verbose=2,
                                epochs=15, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[callback])
```

Comment: You can use class_weight like in this [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52121124/14328644).

Comment: @HweiGeokNg I want to the data to be equally balanced . How can I do this ??

Comment: Check this blog out: https://androidkt.com/set-class-weight-for-imbalance-dataset-in-keras/. There is a function named compute_class_weight() that you can use as the param of the class_weight.

Comment: @HweiGeokNg I know this function but I don't have x_train and y_train in my dataset I use `generate_arrays_for_training` function . please check the code I will this function.

Comment: Sorry I missed that information. I can't help you with this, hopefully someone else would come to the rescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change your data creation process, you can use `class_weight` in your fit generator. You can use dictionary to set your class_weight and observe with fine tuning. For instance when class_weight is not used, and you have 50 examples for class0 and 100 examples for class1. Then, loss function calculate loss uniformly. It means that class1 will be a problem. But, when you set:

```
class_weight = {0:2 , 1:1}
```

It means that loss function will give 2 times weight to your class 0 now. Therefore, misclassification of underrepresented data will take 2 times more punishment than before. Thus, model can handle imbalanced data.

If you use `class_weight='balanced'` model can make that setting automatically. But my suggestion is that, create a dictionary like `class_weight = {0:a1 , 1:a2}` and try different values for a1 and a2, so you can understand difference.

Also, you can use undersampling methods for imbalanced data instead of using class_weight. Check ***Bootstrapping*** methods for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I want to ask How can I determine values of a1 and a2 ??? , I don't know what values should be written for a1 and a2 ??

Comment: You can find ratio between two classes. For instance if number of instance in class1 is 2 times more than class2 you can assign class_weight = {class1: 1, class2: 2} vice versa. Important point is ratio. By the way you can find class names by using `train_generator.classes` to assign class names for class1 and class2.

Comment: very well.Thanks a lot I understood. okay How can I use `train_generator.classes` ??

Comment: I guess in your problem `train_generator.classes` is not necessary.  Also, you can look at here for more information https://groups.google.com/g/keras-users/c/MUO6v3kRHUw?pli=1